# Any reason why the MIC920 op amp should not be used in SINGLE SUPPLY mode?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, single-supply-op-amp, dual-supply

I understand that practically any op amp can be used in single-supply mode as long as the application (interface, measurement, etc) does not require dual-supply for specific reasons.

- Is there a reasons why the [MIC920](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/MIC920YC5-TR/576-4560-1-ND/4805777?itemSeq=364520784) (being a general purpose op amp) does not list single-supply (i.e. 0-5 V) as an option?
- Is there a way to determine if it's rail-to-rail?

The planned use would be amplification of mV level positive-only pulse signals by 100-1000 times between 500 Hz - 20 kHz for reading by an MCU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the *Maximum Output Voltage Swing*.

With \$\pm\$5V supply voltage, the output range is \$\pm\$3V. So your output will not got to ground in a single supply, but will be stuck at a minimum voltage of at least 2V.
With \$\pm\$9V the datasheet is even more conservative and specifies a headroom of -2.8V.

These values are given for a load resisitance of 2k\$\Omega\$, so if your load will be high impedance, then the minimum output voltage will probably be a bit higher.
But the OpAmp is clearly not designed as a single supply device, as the output is not nearly R2R.

---

Figure 2-12 shows you the negative output voltage for \$\pm\$9V supply rails vs. output current - and even at 0mA the output will not go below -8V. So even with a really high impedance load your output would not be able to go lower than 1V above ground.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  So for example, if I use the conventional 3.3V single-supply from a MCU to supply the MIC920, would I get a 0-3V maximum output swing...basically a rail-to-rail output?

Comment: Sorry, just saw the rest of your comments.  I understand.  Not a good fit for a rail-to-rail single-supply op amp.